# gcc error when installing wasm-pack for Rust

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-pack

I encountered an error while trying to install rust-wasm on my machine, it was likely related to `gcc`, is anybody else experiencing this issue or is it just me? I tried searching for it in other places but couldn't find anything!

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
 
warning: bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning:
warning:
 
error: failed to run custom build command for `bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8`
 
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installvhphOY\release\build\bzip2-sys-d16923996b9f6c2a\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-pc-windows-gnu")
  CC_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CC_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-pc-windows-gnu = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_pc_windows_gnu = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_WIN32" "-DBZ_EXPORT" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\My Name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installvhphOY\\release\\build\\bzip2-sys-6cdbad4f0a3b6446\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c"
  cargo:warning=bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
  cargo:warning=
  cargo:warning=
  exit code: 1
 
  --- stderr
 
 
  error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_WIN32" "-DBZ_EXPORT" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\My Name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installvhphOY\\release\\build\\bzip2-sys-6cdbad4f0a3b6446\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c" with args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
 
 
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:
 
warning: src/zlib/adler32.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
warning:  /* adler32.c -- compute the Adler-32 checksum of a data stream
warning:
 
error: failed to compile `wasm-pack v0.10.2`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installvhphOY`
 
Caused by:
  build failed
```

### Culprits?

I know that this issue is tied to my environment, and I think `gcc` is the culprit here. The part where the error occurred was here according to the log:

```
  error occurred: Command "gcc.exe" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-m64" "-I" "bzip2-1.0.8" "-D_WIN32" "-
DBZ_EXPORT" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-DBZ_NO_STDIO" "-o" "C:\\Users\\My Name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installvhphOY\\release\\build\\bzip2-sys-6cdbad4f0a3b6446\\out\\lib\\bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.o" "-c" "bzip2-1.0.8/blocksort.c" with
args "gcc.exe" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
```

### TL;DR

I ran into an error (likely related to GCC) in which the library `bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8` was trying to build.

wasm-pack version: `v0.10.2` 
rustc version: `v1.56.1`
gcc version: `v6.3.0`